# Storing/Saving a Method and later re-calling it

Tags: c#, user-interface, methods, inventory

What I am currently atempting to make is an inventory system. I wonder if I can store the current method and then open the inventory, and when I am done there, reopen/recall the previus method that ran.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided very much information but I can tell you don't want to store a method, you want to store an object.

An object is an instance of a class. Depending on the kind of class you have you can either create multiple instances of a class and instantiate them multiple times across your application. Or alternatively you can create single instances of an object that you use throughout your entire application/game.

From the sounds of it, you want to use a singleton class that retains the current values of the user's inventory. So if you interact with the inventory class in one part of your program, you would like to then view and interact with the same previously modified values stored within the singleton from another part of your program.

I can't give you a concrete answer to your problem, but a possible Singleton class for your use case would look something like this;

```
public sealed class Inventory
{
    private static readonly Inventoryinstance = new Inventory();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as before field init
    static Inventory()
    {
    }

    private Inventory()
    {
        // optionally, pre-populate with data stored in database when constructed
    }

    public static Inventory Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> InventoryItems { get; set; } = new List<InventoryItem>();

    public void AddItemToInventory(InventoryItem item) {
        InventoryItems.Add(item);
    }

    public void RemoveItemFromInventory(InventoryItem item) {
        InventoryItems.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

You can use this site for reference - https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton

If you have an application that utilises DI, you can create singleton instances that are injectable into your other app classes. This is a better way of handling singletons as they are handled by an IoC system rather than being made static for the entire application to access.